# How to Hardcode a NSURL path?

Tags: ios, nsurl

So, this seems like it should be super easy, but i'm stumped...

I have an iOS application that I am developing where I am downloading video content from a server, storing it in a custom folder in the Documents, and upon a certain trigger, trying to play the video. I am experiencing some loading errors in my MovieViewController, so am trying to debug the NSURL that is constructed from the file path in a separate standalone application. It is worth noting that the same content works fine when added to the Bundle, but there's quite a lot, so can't afford to do that.

Anyways...

I have set breakpoints in my app and copied out the path of the NSURL that gets loaded into my movie player, and am attempting to hardcode it into an NSURL in my test app. But I can't seem to just assign it with a preexisting value... Eg.

```
NSURL *url = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/21078F3B-12C5-4D42-8B8B-3C85CB7A0A91/Documents/SecondStory/BloodAlley/MEDIA/copperthief.mp4"
```

(which is what I copied out of the Variables View of the Debug area).
It gives me the error:

*"Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'NSURL *' is disallowed with ARC"*

... which I cannot seem to track down on SO ....

Of course, I have the NSString representation of the file path before it gets converted to an NSURL, so can just try to reconstruct it, but this got me curious why I couldn't just assign a value...

Comment: Dude, someone is relentlessly downvoting every question I make this week... I understand the question had one obvious solution, but I'm trying to do my reasearch and ask worthwhile questions...

Comment: I agree. Some people tend to jump too quickly for down-votes and this in many cases defeats the purpose of SO of sharing ideas, because people will think: ok,, I do not want to risk my points and will not ask the question. As a result, others, who will have the very same problem later will suffer as well. I believe that after a down-vote at least a reason should be given and it would be nice to argue about the question before making a download in non-trivial situations.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, `"file:///var/.../copperthief.mp4"` is a `char *` not an `NSURL`.

To convert it to an `NSURL`, first you have to get the `char *`'s `NSString` representation by adding the **@** prefix:

```
@"file:///var/.../copperthief.mp4"
```

then convert the `NSString` to an `NSURL` using `URLWithString:`:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///var/.../copperthief.mp4"];
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... the @ was there from the Variables View, but it was complaining about being a String... where I copied the value of an NSURL, so got confused...

Comment: SO this begs the question - and maybe this is the real question - what would an NSURL representation look like if I wanted to assign a value to a variable ??

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Huh? If you wanted to assign what value to what variable?

Comment: Reread the question (or is it not clear?). I have a value of an NSURL variable that is giving me problems in my app. I have copied the *value* of that variable and am trying to assign *that value* directly to another instance of an NSURL variable in order to debug that NSURL...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt No, you copied out the *path* of the `NSURL` which is an `NSString`.

Comment: Ok... Sure. So how would I get the exact value of the NSURL ?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by value in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65730/discussion-between-jesses-co-tt-and-lyndsey-scott).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that `"..."` is not an NSString. It's a C string. An NSString would be `@"..."`, wouldn't it? And even then, if you wanted an NSURL, you'd have to *convert* from NSString to NSURL, wouldn't you? I mean, you can't *assign* a string of *any* kind to an NSSURL variable and expect it to work, can you? This is a computer language; you can't say just any old thing that comes into your head - you have to obey the rules.

Comment: Sure, I understand it' a C String and not an NSString... see my comment on @Lyndset-Scott's answer.

Comment: There's a lot more to my answer than that.

Comment: Sure, there is, but your answer came off rather pedantic and accusatory, so I ignored the rest of the issues because the other answer was **helping** to get to the core of the question, not pointing fingers...

Comment: Well, that's not really true. Remember, your question was about the mysterious error message "Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'char *' to 'NSURL ' is disallowed with ARC" My reply tells you what that message means: it means you've used a C string where an Objective-C object was expected. I mean, if you understood it's a C string and not an NSString, why did you do that in the first place? A C string isn't an object; an NSString is. And even if it _were_ an NSString, it would _still_ be the wrong _kind_ of object. But now I'm just repeating myself.

Comment: Fair enough. What happened was this - I set a breakpoint where my URL gets allocated and initialized from a string. I copied that value that the Variables View gave me. I assumed it was a full NSURL representation. Tried to paste it into a new app, making an instance of NSURL from that... It gave me an assignment warning from NSString to NSURL (it copied with the @), so I just lazily took off the @ symbol, converting it to a C string and getting a different error. All naive, sure... but a red herring for the real issue. Will edit question.